# a fourth vs one-fourth

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Example sentence:

> To travel half the distance of a destination, you have to travel a
> fourth/one-fourth of it first.

Is a fourth or one-fourth the correct option? If they're both correct, which is more common?

Comment: to a destination

Comment: 1/4 is usually called _a quarter_.

Comment: @KateBunting - I'd consider the use of 'fourth' rather than 'quarter' to be entirely Am Eng. Brits certainly wouldn't use it, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both *technically* correct. However they are only correct in certain context.

A - "a fourth": *A track is a fourth of a mile.*
B - "one fourth": (note there is no hyphen in AmE) *Subtract one fourth from one half.*

A is correct for literal description and math, but B is usually only good for math. Saying B for distance seems a bit too proper.

Have a good day!